# SQL intersect, union?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables EVENTS, and USER

EVENTS has fields "id", "name", "date"
USER has 1 field "id"

I want an SQL query to get all of the EVENT names of only the events that have the matching id's in USER. In other words, take all of the id's from USER, find the matching id's in EVENTS, display the name of the events that have those id's.

specifically, i want to display a list in html with all of these names

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want an SQL query to get all of the EVENT names of only the events
>   that have the matching id's in USER.

```
create table EVENTS (id number,name varchar2(20), date1 date);
create table user1(id number);

select u.id,e.name
from 
USER1 u
INNER JOIN
EVENTS e
ON u.id = e.id;
```

> In other words, take all of the id's from USER, find the matching id's
>   in EVENTS, display the name of the events that have those id's

```
select u.id,e.name
from 
USER1 u
LEFT OUTER JOIN
EVENTS e
ON u.id = e.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use an inner join for this, to do this your SQL should look something like this:

```
SELECT events.id, name, user.id
FROM events
INNER JOIN user ON events.id = user.id;
```

I would also advise against using block capitals for table names etc. Not that there is any technical reason for it, only it makes queries etc more readable.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`:

```
select e.*
from events e
where exists (select 1 from user u where u.id = e.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use it directly using a WHERE Statement

```
select u.id,e.name
from 
USER u,EVENTS e
where u.id = e.id;
```